# Autocomplete feature for UITextField in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, autocompletetextview

I'm accomplishing the concept of AutoCompleteTextView in iPhone similar to we find when we go for safari..I'm doing it with the help of UITableView.But Im getting error "Program received signal SIGABRT" Could not understand where I m going wrong ..?

My array looks like this :

```
(
        {
        Name = "John";
    },
        {
        Name = "Williams ";
    },
        {
        Name = "Michael ";
    },
        {
        Name = "Hillary ";
    },
        {
        Name = "Jennifer ";
    },
)
```

so I have to get the values of Name in cells of tableView..

```
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {


    [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
    for(int i=0;i<[arr2 count];i++)
    {
        for(NSString *curString in [[arr2 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"]) //error :Program recieved signal SIGABRT
       {
        NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
        if (substringRange.location == 0) 
        {
            [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  
        }
       }
    }
    [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


    if( textField == txtcity)
    {
        [txtcity resignFirstResponder];
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
    return YES;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {
    return autocompleteUrls.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [autocompleteUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    txtcity.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

}
```

I m getting error at this line : `for(NSString *curString in [[arr2 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"])`

Where I m going wrong..? Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: When you program halts look at the debug console (from the menu, select View -> Debug Area -> Activate Console).  It will contain a message that describes what the problem is.

Comment: what is the value of curString in your code?

Comment: This is the thing I m getting in activeconsole: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60d3660'

Comment: My curlString value is: UserProfile....But I should not get it .Actually when I keep the cursor at see at curlString it says :Variable is not a CFString ..But when I print description it shows UserProfile..This UserProfile is the name of my UIView..Where I m going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for(NSString *curString in arr2)
```

or

```
for(int i=0;i<[arr2 count];i++)
{
     NSString *curString = [[arr2 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"]
     curString = [curString lowercaseString];
     substring = [substring lowercaseString];

     if ([curString rangeOfString:substring].location == NSNotFound) 
     {} 
     else 
     { 
          [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString] 
     }  
}
```

Comment: When I try :for(NSString *curString in arr2]) Now I m getting error at this line  : NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];I think it is because of NSRange .When I check in substringRange value its location is 3221216248. and length is 16212608.and error is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x689a5e0'"

Comment: Can you print the count of your array before using this for and let me know.

Comment: Its count is not fixed.It may or maynot change.As of now it is 8...and in my code substringRange location is going on changing .It is not fixed .It is 0 sometimes,16,3, 2147483647 ......How can I make it accept all values ?

Comment: Did you try the second method?

Comment: ya gone for it but location is gng on changing...It is not fixed i.e 0.So items are not getting added up

Comment: @arizah:I've edited my answer can you please try this. I don't see there's any mistake in the technique.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19368/discussion-between-rushi-and-arizah)

Comment: Hey sorry to ask u a question again.Actually in our last conversation regarding autocomplete uitextfield I have some doubt.How can I get autocomplete feature whatever the location may be.Prevoisly I did it for 0 location for(int i=0;i<[arr2 count];i++)
    {
        NSString *curString = [[arr2 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"];
        curString = [curString lowercaseString];
        NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
        if (substringRange.location == 0) 
            [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}

Comment: Now what I want is if I type letter o then irrespective of location in the array if that character is found then i have to get autocomplete feature for UITextField.How can I do it?Please help

Answer (score 0):

`[[arr2 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"]` will return a string (a name), not an array. Therefore you don't need that for loop.

Just assign the name you're returning to the variable:

```
for(int i=0;i<[arr2 count];i++)
    {
        NSString *curString = [[arr2 objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"]

        NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
        if (substringRange.location == 0) 
        {
            [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  
        }
    }
```